# Is Connected $\rightarrow$ Dense?

Tags: general-topology

As part of a proof that connected components are closed the following step was written.

$X$ is a topologic space, let $C$ be a connected component, therefore it is connected, moreover **$C$ is dense in $\bar{C}$**

Why can we conclude this?

Comment: The definition of "$A$ is dense in $B$" is $\overline{A}=B$. Then of course $C$ is dense in $\overline{C}$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe but why it is dense?

Comment: Maybe it is better to see it this way: if $C$ is connected then so is $\overline C$ and since $C$ is a component, then $C\supseteq \overline C$ so...

Comment: So is your question why $C$ is dense in $\overline C$?

Comment: @PaulFrost yes, all we know that $C$ is connected, how did they conclude that it is dense in $\bar{C}$?

Comment: @Matematleta There is no need to talk about connectedness. All sets are dense in their closure. Just apply the definition.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes, obviously. Thanks!  I am supposing that it is the wording of the proof that was giving the OP trouble. That is, you do not need to even use the word "dense" in the proof.

Comment: @Matematleta I think the proof goes on with something like: $C$ is dense and connected in $\overline{C}$ so $\overline{C}$ is also connected (standard theorem) and by maximality of components and $C \subseteq \overline{C}$ we conclude $C=\overline{C}$ and all components are closed sets.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Isn't the word dense superfluous? That is my point, I mean, $C$ is always dense in its closure, by definition. So all you need is the fact the the closure of a connected set is connected (in the topology of the ambient space). Or am I missing something? I am being dense!?

Comment: @Matematleta The OP knows the theorem that "if a space $X$ has a dense connected subspace then $X$ is connected." So we need to mention denseness to see the theorem applies to $\overline{C}$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I see. OK.

Answer (score 3):

Any set is dense in its closure.  Namely, $\overline C=\overline C$.  This has nothing to do with connectedness.

Answer (score 1):

For a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ to be dense in $X$ means that $\operatorname{Cl}_X(A)=X$ (index denotes the space in which the closure is taken). So "$C$ is dense in $\operatorname{Cl}_X(C)$" is to say that $\operatorname{Cl}_{\operatorname{Cl}_X(C)}(C)=\operatorname{Cl}_X(C)$, but this is true (for any $C\subseteq X$). Obviously, $\operatorname{Cl}_{\operatorname{Cl}_X(C)}(C)\subseteq\operatorname{Cl}_X(C)$ by definition. On the other hand, if $x\in\operatorname{Cl}_X(C)$, there is a net $(x_{\alpha})$ in $C$ that converges to $x$ in $X$, but, since $x\in\operatorname{Cl}_X(C)$, the net $(x_{\alpha})$ in $C$ also converges to $x$ in $\operatorname{Cl}_X(C)$, hence $x\in\operatorname{Cl}_{\operatorname{Cl}_X(C)}(C)$.

Comment: To show that $\operatorname{Cl}_{\operatorname{Cl}_X(C)}(C)=\operatorname{Cl}_X(C)$ you do not need nets. $D = \operatorname{Cl}_{\operatorname{Cl}_X(C)}(C)$ is a closed subset of $\operatorname{Cl}_X(C)$, hence closed in  $X$ and therefore  $\operatorname{Cl}_X(C) \subset D$ since $C  \subset D$.